# Do I need a Samba share if I have SFTP working?

Tags: samba, sftp

I have a virtual Ubuntu server set up, and the only file-sharing required is between my windows host and the `/var/www` directory on the Ubuntu server. I using this setup primarily for Wordpress configs. What I've already done is created another user called **wwwuser** and assigned him to the `www-data` group with read/write permissions as follows:

```
sudo usermod -g www-data wwwuser
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www
```

Using FileZilla I can sFTP to the `/var/www` folder successfully and read+write to it. The only case where I can see Samba benefiting me is if I need to transfer files from the Samba share directly to a live remote server.

Am I missing something else? Apologies also, I am relatively new to Linux in general, but  learning more all the time.

Comment: I realise that in my case the sFTP setup is redundant if I'm only using samba for this kind of file-sharing, buts also useful for me to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need Samba. Even in your "only" case, you could just connect to the remote server directly - you wouldn't need Samba for that.

Comment: just btw, I went ahead and created a samba user anyway with read-only access to `/var/www` and then mapped a network drive to it in Windows. Reason being that FileZilla does not allow server-to-server transfers. So now in FileZilla, I can have my Ubuntu Server VM showing up in the left-hand side under "local site" and then my hosting provider's "remote site" on the right-hand side.